# that/which after a subject-verb-object

Tags: that

In the sentence below, I want to make it clear that the **statistic** (rather than the **sample**) is the subject doing the **estimating**.

> A **statistic** is a numerical characteristic of a **sample, that
>   estimates** the numerical characteristic (or parameter) of the population from which it is drawn.

This sentence, from a lecture I attended, is introducing two new pieces of information about a sample--*i.e.* it is a numerical characteristic, and it estimates something--, so neither is just 'additional information', in that sense.

Maybe the structure could be changed:

> A **statistic** is a numerical characteristic of a **sample; it
>   estimates** the numerical characteristic (or parameter) of the population from which it is drawn.

But if I wanted to keep the same structure and flow of the original sentence, (which I do), how should it be done correctly and unambiguously?

Comment: I'm thinking now that "from which it is drawn" should be "from which the sample is drawn".

Comment: A **statistic** is a sample's numerical characteristic that estimates that same characteristic for the population from which the sample is drawn.

Comment: Isn't the statistic "an estimate".  You are the one doing the estimating.